# Get-PnPfile by id

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

If I want to download a file from sharepoint online within a powershell script I can use:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url $filePath -Path $LocalFolder -Filename $fileName -AsFile -force
```

However I have a database of item **id's** instead of file names. I know the folder they exist in and I want to download them by **id**.

The **ID's** that exist in the DB are **fileId** I think.

Comment: You may want to use [Get-PnPFolderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfolderitem?view=sharepoint-ps) to get a list of all files in the folder and use a `Where-Object {}` clause to filter on the `fileId`